# How to convert Grayscale image to Color in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics, bufferedimage

Could you point me in the right direction to find a tutorial on how to convert a grayscale image to it's original colors? Is this even possible?

I've tried using BufferedImage and applying a function to the RGB values by bitshifting them 8 bits to the left and isolating the reds, but, of course, there are no reds that are found, as it is grayscale.

I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction!

Comment: We need a close-vote option for: "what you're requesting is impossible and illogical".

Comment: You could use [LookupOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/LookupOp.html) to apply colors to a gray image (basically mapping a color to a gray scale intensity), but of course, this will not give you back the original colors.

Comment: Yep, it will provide a "false-color" image.

Comment: Thank you haraldK for your suggestion, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

`"Is this even possible?"` -- No, not a prayer's chance in Hades. Once you have a grayscale image, all color information is gone.

Comment: Well if that's the case, then how do film studios change their black and white movies into full color?

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin What could have happened was that when they were filming, all of the color information was there in the raw footage to begin with, and they could only show in grayscale because television technology hadn't caught up yet. Once it did, then they could convert the raw footage into film and keep the color.

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes, I see, that makes complete sense! Thanks for your reply

Comment: @DennisMeng: no, you're wrong. The old movies were filmed in black and white. To colorize it they simply guessed at a color and "painted" using computers colors that they felt were as realistic as possible. The information was not present in the black and white, and the old film was indeed black and white.

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin: what you are trying to do, to regain true color information that was lost, is completely impossible to do. You can guess and paint, but you can't re-create. Please look at colorized movies and ask yourself how true-to-life they are, especially people's faces, and you'll see.

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin: for more on grayscale please have a look at [grayscale wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale).